# Permission denied to Docker on Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Docker is installed on AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 instance as follows:

[image]

`docker info` raises a permission denied error:

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

`docker -v` shows:

```
Docker version 18.09.4, build d14af54
```

uname -a displays:

```
4.4.0-1072-aws #82-Ubuntu SMP
```

sudo snap start docker cannot find 'docker'.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Are you root? Is your user in the `docker` group?

Comment: No, mine is ubuntu. I don't think the user is in the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `ubuntu` user to the `docker` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu
```

Comment: Remember that being able to `docker run` anything at all gives you the ability to read and modify literally any file on the system as root.  There are good security-oriented reasons to _not_ do this (that then require `sudo` to run any Docker command).